Do "dynamic" menu letter keyboard shortcuts work in Version 14 under Linux?
Under Windows in previous versions (and I believe in Version 14) I can select text, type alt+r then glenter to set the background of the selected input to light gray. Typing l multiple times moves through selections beginning with the letter "L", "Light Blue", "Light Brown", etc.
I use that a lot! but it is not working for me under Linux in Version 14.0 for x86(64 bit).  Is that the experience of others as well?

That is likely a behavior specific to Windows.

I'm pretty sure it used to work under Linux in ancient times.

Maybe.  Could be window manager specific.  We did not add explicit support for this behavior on Windows.
